Is there a way to copy/get responses directly from chrome browser with python?
I have a python code that uses selenium, I'm not expert with web development and I'm trying to get responses from some dropdowns that are cascading each other, when you select a value from one dropdown it retrieves a response with the values of the next dropdown. One of those is a date picker that contains available days in JSON format instead of going through the calendar, I can know which one is available by getting this JSON response, I found a feature in Google Chrome that allows you to get this information if you open the developer tools and go to the Network tab -> right-click to the file -> copy -> copy response, is there any way to do the same or use this feature with code using python and selenium or maybe pure JavaScript? Selenium allows you to run JavaScript commands
Please see what I'm trying to explain in the below picture with Google:

I have found some suggested solutions in this post:
Selenium - python. how to capture network traffic's response
But not sure if there's any other straight-forward solution as I mentioned directly from browser.
